# Centos: multiple IP addresses

Tags: centos, ip, ip-aliasing

I just bought 10 extra IPs from my host. How do I point these at my CentOS 5 server?

Comment: I assume that is is a question about how to configure the host, not how to route the addresses.

Answer (score 8):

On CentOS you can use a ifcfg-eth?-range? file to assign multiple IP adresses. For example; you want to assign additional IP adresses to your eth0 interface and you don't have any additional addresses assigned yet. Create the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0-range0`:

```
IPADDR_START=10.0.0.10
IPADDR_END=10.0.0.19
CLONENUM_START=0
```

When you already have assigned additional IP addresses the CLONENUM_START value should match the next available eth0:x number.

If the IP addresses aren't in order you have to create an ifcfg-eth0:x file for each of the addresses. The content should look like this:

```
DEVICE=eth0:0
IPADDR=10.0.0.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes
```

Change the DEVICE value to the corresponding filename and run ifup eth0:0 to bring the interface online.

Comment: the IPs are all over the range though, not in order.

Answer (score 6):

Use IP aliasing on the host.

```
ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.0.100 netmask 255.255.255.0
ifconfig eth0:2 192.168.0.101 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

To do it permanently you will have to use the files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<interface>`

And so on. But why do you need multiple IPs for a single host? SSL/TLS?

Comment: Check the answer from PowerSp00n for how to setup the ifcfg files.

Comment: multiple IPs for SEO benefit.  Hosting a lot of sites that link together on the same server, but want the benefit of the search engine thinking they are on different servers.

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me.

If you are on `Centos Web panel` then you can add the multiple ip address using this method:

1. Create a file as: 
   `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:0`
2. Add the following line on the created file:

   ```
   DEVICE="eth0:0"
   BOOTPROTO=static
   ONBOOT=yes
   TYPE="Ethernet"
   IPADDR=80.80.25.25
   HWADDR=00:0C:29:28:4C:4C
   GATEWAY=80.80.25.1
   NETMASK=255.255.255.0
   ```
3. Restart the network

   ```
   service network restart
   ```
4. Check the network for any success

   ```
   ifconfig
   ```

Source:  http://wiki.centos-webpanel.com/add-additional-ip-address