# How to BIND IP Address on Centos 5? Need Tutorial

Tags: bind

Can someone show me a simplified tutorial that explains how to bind IPs in Linux (Centos / Redhat)?

For example, got a dedicated server with a /29

123.123.123.0/29

So I have to bind that /29 where 123.123.123.2 is the IP I'll access via ssh in order to do so.

Thanks.

Comment: Check my recently posted answer for this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/131339/centos-multiple-ip-addresses/131366#131366

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CentOS is based on Red Hat Enterprise Linux.  I've linked some of their documentation.  If you have a more detailed question, we will likely be able to assist further.

[Interface Configuration Files](https://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-4-Manual/ref-guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html)