# bond0:0 + define virtual IP

Tags: linux

in my linux server I have the follwoing:

Linux Version - RedHat-Linux- 5.3.0.0

(this linux server only only one LAN)

```
   more /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0:0

   DEVICE=bond0:0
   ONBOOT=yes
   BOOTPROTO=static
   IPADDR=10.10.10.12
   NETMASK=255.255.255.0




 ifconfig -a
           bond0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
           UP BROADCAST MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
           RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

           bond0:0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
           inet addr:10.10.10.12  Bcast:1.1.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
           UP BROADCAST MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

           eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0E:0C:C7:F8:92  
           inet addr:1.1.1.1  Bcast:1.1.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
           inet6 addr: fe80::20e:cff:fec7:f892/64 Scope:Link
           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:8600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:4764 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
           RX bytes:717979 (701.1 KiB)  TX bytes:598620 (584.5 KiB)
           Memory:b8820000-b8840000
```

my problems:

1. why I get HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00 and not the real MAC address
2. I cant ping to other server with 10.10.10.11 from my server
3. is it posible to define bond0:0 when I have only one LAN (eth0)

other info:

more /etc/modprobe.conf

```
 alias eth0 e1000e
 alias eth1 e1000e
 alias eth2 e1000e
 alias eth3 e1000e
 alias scsi_hostadapter mptbase
 alias scsi_hostadapter1 mptsas
 alias scsi_hostadapter2 ata_piix
 alias bond0 bonding
 alias bond1 bonding
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is your bond associated with eth0?
2. (see 1)
3. Theoretically: yes but it makes no sense to do so. (see below)

A bonded interface is for taking two *physical* interfaces and combining the bandwidth. If you have 2x1Gbps ports, you can configure the switch to treat them as 1x2Gbps port.

It sounds like what you want is an [IP Aliases or Range](https://serverfault.com/questions/131339/centos-multiple-ip-addresses)

**UPDATE**

If you really do want to set up a bond, then [Red Hat's](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-networkscripts-interfaces-chan.html) documentation may help.

Comment: yes I want to add to eth0 the bond0:0 is it wrong?

Comment: @yael "not 'wrong' per se; it's just a bit of unnecessary complexity". If you really want a bond set up, I added a link to Red Hat's documentation on it. However, it really sounds as though you want IP Aliases.

Answer (score 1):

A bond interface will show the all-zeros MAC until it has at least one member (slave) interface added to it (via the ifenslave command).

On RedHat (and similar), you'll add two lines to the physical interface's sysconfig script:
'MASTER=bond0' and 'SLAVE=yes'. Then set the IP in a new sysconfig script for the bond0 interface.

You can have as many alias subinterfaces (:0, :1, etc) as you want, regardless of the number of physical interfaces the machine has.

A bond group with only 1 physical interface is a little unusual, but not 'wrong' per se; it's just a bit of unnecessary complexity. When you do get more interfaces, be sure to set the 'mode' parameter for the bonding module -- the modes work in very different ways, depending on your intended application.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use a bonded connection with one interface?

I'm pretty sure creating a bonded device generally requires two or more interfaces.

I think what you're trying to do will require either an alias interface (eth0:N) or a VLAN configuration.

Comment: hi I need two diffrent ip's , this is the reson for that

Comment: I return on my question , I have only one LAN , but I need to define the second IP 10.10.10.12 as CHB (cluster hart bit) because I want to add this server as second cluster machine,

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

> I return on my question , I have only one LAN , but I need to define the second IP 10.10.10.12 as CHB (cluster hart bit) because I want to add this server as second cluster machine,  – yael yesterday

A bonded connection is not the solution you need in this situation.

What you need is an aliased connection.

With RedHat based systems, this is very easy to do.

copy /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 file to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:0

Edit the ifcfg-eth0:0 so that you remove the HWADDR section and obviously change the IP to the second IP you want on the same interface. 
Also change the DEVICE to read eth0:0

Restart networking and you should see the new IP address on your network.